# How to get single variable in a loop in PHP

Tags: php, for-loop

I have the following loop, that print for each 'index' a relative section in some arrays.

```
for ($index = 0; $index < count($photo); $index++) {
?>
<div id="general" style="margin-left: 140px;">

    <?php

echo "<img src='$photo[$index]'>" . "<img src='$rating[$index]'>" . "$city[$index]" . 'name    : '."$name[$index]" . 'address : '."$address[$index]";
?>
</div>
    <?php       
}
```

For example :

Photo,rating,city,address (position 0 in array photo,in array rating , in array city, in array address)

Photo,rating,city,address(position 1 in array photo,in array rating , in array city, in array address)

Photo,rating,city,address (position 2 in array photo,in array rating , in array city, in array address)

Now, I would like to create a button or link for each position that returns the relative value and send each value as a variable in PHP .

I'm trying to do this with the following modification(in bold) in the previous code :

```
for ($index = 0; $index < count($photo); $index++) {
?>
<div id="general" style="margin-left: 140px;">
      **<a href="new.php"> City : <?php $_SESSION['city']=$cit[$index]; ?> /a>**
    <?php

echo "<img src='$photo[$index]'>" . "<img src='$rating[$index]'>" . "$city[$index]" . 'name    : '."$name[$index]" . 'address : '."$address[$index]";
?>
</div>
    <?php       
}
```

But when I click on Name (the Link),for example the first entry, I receive the last entry, for all entry chosen.

Could you help me? Thanks

Comment: what are you expecting this `<?php $_SESSION['city']=$cit[$index]; ?>` to do?? And your `</a>` misses a `<`

Comment: your _SESSION assignment is creating a single value, and you overwrite it on every loop iteration. You'd probably want `$_SESSSION['city'] = $cit` OUTSIDE the loop, so the entire array gets copied into the sessino.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because session is single shared variable when u set it at the end of loop for last city it overwrite rest of it . Session[city] is variable not array

Try this ..

New.php?city=".city[$index]

In new.php get city like this

$city=$_GET['city'];